# Why does this git rebase think there's nothing to do?

Tags: git

In this example, git doesn't think it needs to rebase, but it clearly does.

Here's a quick script to create a mini test git repository

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf testgit
mkdir testgit
cd testgit
git init
echo -e "a\nb\nc" > file
git add file
git commit -am 'first'

git checkout -b lineA
echo -e "A\nb\nc" > file
git commit -am 'A'

git checkout -b lineB
echo -e "a\nB\nc" > file
git commit -am 'B'

git checkout -b lineC
echo -e "a\nb\nC" > file
git commit -am 'C'
```

After this runs, here's what `file` looks like in each branch

```
master | lineA | lineB | lineC
------------------------------

a        A       a       a
b        b       B       b
c        c       c       C
```

Now let's merge all the branches into master, after which each letter in `file` should be capitalised

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge lineA
```

Okay.

```
$ git checkout lineB
$ git rebase master
Current branch lineB is up to date.
```

What? No, master changed.

```
$ git checkout master
$ cat file
A
b
c

$ git checkout lineB
$ cat file
a
B
c
```

It seems to me that branch lineB needs to rebase to incorporate the change to master made by merging lineA.

**Why doesn't git think this needs to be done?**

Additionally, if you do this

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge lineA
Already up-to-date.
$ git merge lineB
...
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
$ cat file
a
B
c
$ git merge lineC
...
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
$ cat file
a
b
C
```

Here the merges should conflict, but git is quietly clobbering them. I'm don't know if this is relevant, but it seems weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Result of the First Commands**

After the script we have (abbreviating the line branch names...):

```
master   lA   lB   lC
  ↓      ↓    ↓    ↓
first----A----B----C
```

These commands:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge lineA
```

results in a fast-forward merge, which just moves `master` to point to the same commit as `lineA`.

Giving:

```
        master 
         lA   lB   lC
         ↓    ↓    ↓
first----A----B----C
```

**No Work for the Rebase**

So this sequence of commands:

```
$ git checkout lineB
$ git rebase master
```

is saying move the `lineB` branch on top of `master`.

...but it is already on top of `master`.

`master` would have to have some commits in its history that `lineB` does not have for the rebase command to have any work to do.

**No Merge Conflict**

When Git creates a merge commit it considers the history of the parents that are going into the merge. In this case both branches are pointing to commits on a common chain of commits. Git can see that the `A` commit came before the `B` commit which came before the `C` commit. As such Git considers the later commits to be additions on top of the earlier commits and as such they do not conflict.

If instead you had a history like:

```
       master
         ↓
      ---A
     /
     |   lB
     |   ↓
first----B
```

then Git would see them as parallel lines of development. In that case merging `lB` into `master` or vice-versa would conflict. This is because  `B` is not an addition on top of `A` in the history and as such Git needs user input to understand which of the changes to keep.

Comment: i think the same. use git extension to see your branches tree shape. for me all your created branches have their origin on master, so git tells you in its way that no rebase is needed. at this point you just have to merge

Answer (score 1):

I think your point of confusion is further back. When you executed

```
git commit -am 'first'
git checkout -b lineA
```

you did create a new branch called `lineA` but the branching-off point was the commit you just did ("`first`"). As Git puts it, `first` is part of the history of both branches, and at that point in your script it is also the most recent commit in both branches. Git log with some options shows that both branch names point to the first commit, which in this example is commit id 58b7dcf:

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate
* 58b7dcf (HEAD, master, lineA) first
```

Continuing:

```
echo -e "A\nb\nc" > file
git commit -am 'A'
git log --graph --oneline --decorate
* ed40ed2 (HEAD, lineA) A
* 58b7dcf (master) first
```

The log command shows that commit `A` (ed40ed2) is now the most recent commit on `lineA`, and its parent commit is `first`, which is still the most recent commit on `master`. If you were to merge `lineA` back to `master` at this time it would be a fast-forward (trivial) merge, because no commits were made to `master` since `lineA` branched off from it.  Likewise, rebasing `lineA` onto `master` would do nothing except report

```
Current branch lineA is up to date.
```

because the most recent commit on branch `master` (the tip of the master branch) is still part of the history of branch `lineA`. Continuing:

```
git checkout -b lineB
echo -e "a\nB\nc" > file
git commit -am 'B'
git checkout -b lineC
echo -e "a\nb\nC" > file
git commit -am 'C'
git log --graph --oneline --decorate
* 4033067 (HEAD, lineC) C
* f742aed (lineB) B
* ed40ed2 (lineA) A
* 58b7dcf (master) first
```

Each new branch is built on the most recent commit of the previous one, with no parallel development going on. Continuing:

```
git checkout master
git merge lineA
Updating 58b7dcf..ed40ed2
Fast-forward
```

Notice this is a fast-forward merge, so all it did was move `master` to ed40ed2:

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate
* ed40ed2 (HEAD, master, lineA) A
* 58b7dcf first
```

Finally:

```
git checkout lineB
git rebase master
Current branch lineB is up to date.
git log --graph --oneline --decorate
* f742aed (HEAD, lineB) B
* ed40ed2 (master, lineA) A
* 58b7dcf first
```

You wrote:

> What? No, master changed.

Yes, `master` changed, but not in a way that affected the history of `lineB` or `lineC`. `master` was fast-forward to commit ed40ed2, which was already the parent of `lineB`. To be precise, it's the parent of f742aed, which is the commit id I got for commit `B`.

The confusion, for people used to other version control systems, is that Git records a tree-like data structure (technically a DAG) for the commit records, not the branch names. The branches are ephemeral; they're just labels, like movable version tags. The parent-child relationships between the commits is what you see in `git log --graph` and other visualization tools.